# Can't show all the values on line chart in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

[Line and stacked column chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnYPq.png)

This is my line and stacked column chart, I can't see all the datas on the line chart. Green area is not so important it only shows my upper limit. When I export the data from this visualization I get the file as csv as follows:

[Exported data file as csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8p2B.png)

As you see in the max of cycle time column there are values that not exists in the line chart. (Also I changed the position name values to share in this platform, there is no problem about in matches x axis values name and column position name in csv)

[Visualization part at the right side looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apG0t.png)

And this is the visualization part of the line and stacked column chart. Is there anyone experienced something like that before? I tried so many ways but I couldn't find a solution about that. Thank you for spending time for me. Have a nice day!

I tried to change column names and tried to create this visualization again but I couldn't get any solution. I've tried to change settings on the visualization part and checked the filters again and again but it looks like nothing solving my problem.